# Fit image into datagridview column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've a datagridview of height and width 300x300 size. I'm reading image from memory stream. I want to resize image into datagridview column such that it fit in it. I've following code

this is code to read image from database

```
byte[] img = (byte[])(dataReader[5]);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
```

code for adding items in datagridview

```
 DataGridView1.Rows.Add( Image.FromStream(ms));
```

Above code crops my image and display 300X300 size of image.

Comment: You can resize the bitmap: `DataGridView1.Rows.Add( new Bitmap ( (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms), newSize);` but @Berkey's answer is much nicer. Note that you can also use `DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DataGridViewImageColumn` which has `ImageLayout` property,

```
byte[] img = (byte[])(dataReader[5]);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
DataGridViewImageColumn imageCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imageCol.HeaderText = "test1";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(imageCol);
imageCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch; // will do the trick
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Image.FromStream(ms));
```

Hope helps,